# jQuery input field error: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery

I encountered a strange problem:

I have a input field in my form for RFID tag scanning:

```
<input id="readRfidTag">
<div id="scanResult"></div>
```

The jQuery for retrieving the scanned ID is:

```
var tagID;
$(document).on('keypress', '#readRfidTag', function(e) {
  if (e.which!=13) {   // Enter is pressed
    return;
  }
  tagID = $('#readRfidTag').val();
});
```

If the scanned tag ID begins with a number, everything is fine. However, if it begins with an English letter, there will be an error. I checked with Chrome's developer tool (F12) as shown in the attached picture, it is OK if I entered '123', however, 'e456' causes the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e456 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

The data beginning with a letter seems to be treated as a variable (instead of a string), which is not defined. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: `$` is missing in `tagID = ('#readRfidTag').val();`

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo and is corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are entering those in the browser console.... if so a numeric value is considered as a literal and is processed as such.. but a value like `e456` is considered to be a variable name, since such a variable is not found the error is thrown... if you are lookging a a string literal try `'e456'`